# Machine learning gridsearch for svm

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, grid-search

I was doing a project where I needed to calculate the best estimator returned by gridsearch.

```
parameters = {'gamma':[0.1, 0.5, 1, 10, 100], 'C':[1, 5, 10, 100, 1000]}

# TODO: Initialize the classifier
svr = svm.SVC()

# TODO: Make an f1 scoring function using 'make_scorer' 
f1_scorer = make_scorer(score_func)

# TODO: Perform grid search on the classifier using the f1_scorer as the scoring method
grid_obj = grid_search.GridSearchCV(svr, parameters, scoring=f1_scorer)

# TODO: Fit the grid search object to the training data and find the optimal parameters
grid_obj = grid_obj.fit(X_train, y_train)
pred = grid_obj.predict(X_test)
def score_func():
    f1_score(y_test, pred, pos_label='yes')

# Get the estimator
clf = grid_obj.best_estimator_
```

I am not sure how to make the f1_scorer func since i make the prediction after creating the gridsearch object. I cannot declare f1_scorer after creating the obj because gridsearch uses it as a scoring method. Please help me how to create this scoring function for gridsearch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
clf = svm.SVC()

# TODO: Make an f1 scoring function using 'make_scorer' 
f1_scorer = make_scorer(f1_score,pos_label='yes')

# TODO: Perform grid search on the classifier using the f1_scorer as the scoring method
grid_obj = GridSearchCV(clf,parameters,scoring=f1_scorer)

# TODO: Fit the grid search object to the training data and find the optimal parameters
grid_obj = grid_obj.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Get the estimator
clf = grid_obj.best_estimator_
```

Answer (score 0):

The scorer function that you pass to `make_scorer` should take `y_true`
and `y_pred` as parameters. With that information you have everything you need to calculate the score. Then GridSearchCV will fit and call the score function for you internally for each possible set of parameters, you don't need to calculate y_pred beforehand.

It should look like this:

```
def score_func(y_true, y_pred):
    """Calculate f1 score given the predicted and expected labels"""
    return f1_score(y_true, y_pred, pos_label='yes')

f1_scorer = make_scorer(score_func)
GridSearchCV(svr, parameters, scoring=f1_scorer)
```

Comment: thanks! that worked percectly. if i may ask, how does gridsearch return the predictions on its own? has it got something to do with the make_scorer function?

Comment: the same way you did it, by using the `.predict()`
 method of the estimator. It splits the data internally into validation and test sets. Then fits to the training set (which is a subset of `X_train, y_train`) and predicts and compares with its internal test set (which is also a subset of `X_train, y_train`). So it never uses your `X_test`. That is for you to evaluate your final model without bias